# Can I get the link of IMA ad?

Tags: javascript, adsense, google-dfp

Can I get the redirecting link of an IMA ad after it is loaded?

Is there any possible chance for that. Like this one:

```
<script>
    addirectlink = event.getAdsManager(videoTag).href;
    document.getElementById('adlink').href = addirectlink;
</script>

<a href="#" id="adlink">Learn More</a>
```

Comment: why would you do so ? The IMA SDK is handling the ad click itself and all the related tracking events...

Comment: I need to track the link. Like I wanted to know from which URL (actually video uploaded user) the ad has been clicked. I saw GameMonetize. The use DFP and they track individual Clicks. My grammar is bad. I think you can understand!

Comment: thing is it is the adserver that is tracking clicks, impressions and other video datas (completion rate...etc). I you really need to retrieve the clickthrough url, you should parse the vast tag and look for the clickthrough tag

Comment: I found What I am searching for! I used Click event. But it is not logging when the ad clicked. But when the learn more link clicked it fires the event. Do you know something about it?